# What does Critical: Database Files, Volumes mean in Opserver?

Tags: opserver

I am looking into the Opserver tool, and have set it up pointing at a variety of servers on our system.

In the SQL section, many of these are highlighted as red. In the `issues` drop down at the top, they are listed as `Critical: Database Files, Volumes`.

I can drill down for more information, but the next screen doesn't have anything in red on it. Where do I need to look to see why these have been marked as critical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because those servers were old versions of SQL, and didn't support the queries used to find information about the databases and volumes. This was a bug that has since been fixed.
See here for the issue raised on github:
https://github.com/opserver/Opserver/issues/133